# Custom layouts for catalog_category_view on Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I need to be able to use different layouts for different categories, selected on the *Custom Design* tab on the category and *Page Layout* field.

I'm using Magento 1.9.1.0.

In my config.xml I have:

```
<global>
    <page>
        <layouts>
            <module_home module="page" translate="label">
                <label>Module Home</label>
                <template>page/base.phtml</template>
                <layout_handle>module_home</layout_handle>
            </module_home>

            <module_categories module="page" translate="label">
                <label>Module Categories</label>
                <template>page/base.phtml</template>
                <layout_handle>module_categories</layout_handle>
            </module_categories>
        </layouts>
    </page>
    ...
```

And in my `layouts.xml` file I have:

```
<default>
    <reference name="root">...</reference>
</default>
<module_home translate="label">...</module_home>
<module_categories translate="label">...</module_categories>
```

When I select *Module Categories* layout from the admin of the category I don't get the changes for *module_categories* handler, only the ones set on `<default>`.

If I force it like this:

```
<catalog_category_view>
    <update handle="module_categories" />
</catalog_category_view>
```

I do get the changes, but I want multiple handlers, selected as Layouts on the admin.

Maybe I'm doing something wrong? Could not find an example for how to do this, maybe you can point somewhere? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got the right idea with the `<update />` directive. Just put it in your category's `Custom Layout Update` field in the admin, and that category should apply that layout handle. You can still set the page template with the `Page Layout` field.

The reason you need to explicitly specify the layout handle with the `<update />` directive is because Magento's category controller does not use the `layout_handle` node, whereas other parts of Magento, like Magento's CMS page controller, do use it.

For example, let's look at `Mage_Cms_PageController`, which is responsible for rendering a CMS page:

```
public function viewAction()
{
    $pageId = $this->getRequest()
        ->getParam('page_id', $this->getRequest()->getParam('id', false));
    if (!Mage::helper('cms/page')->renderPage($this, $pageId)) {
        $this->_forward('noRoute');
    }
}
```

Let's dig deeper and look at `Mage_Cms_Helper_Page::renderPage()`, which calls `Mage_Cms_Helper_Page::_renderPage()`:

```
protected function _renderPage(Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action  $action, $pageId = null, $renderLayout = true)
{

    $page = Mage::getSingleton('cms/page');

    /* ... */

    if ($page->getRootTemplate()) {
        $handle = ($page->getCustomRootTemplate()
                    && $page->getCustomRootTemplate() != 'empty'
                    && $inRange) ? $page->getCustomRootTemplate() : $page->getRootTemplate();
        $action->getLayout()->helper('page/layout')->applyHandle($handle);
    }

    /* ... */

    if ($page->getRootTemplate()) {
        $action->getLayout()->helper('page/layout')
            ->applyTemplate($page->getRootTemplate());
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

We see two important pieces of logic here.

First, `_renderPage()` calls `$action->getLayout()->helper('page/layout')->applyHandle($handle)`. If you dig even deeper, you'll see that `Mage_Page_Helper_Layout::applyHandle()` is responsible for applying the appropriate `layout_handle` as defined by the configuration XML:

```
public function applyHandle($pageLayout)
{
    $pageLayout = $this->_getConfig()->getPageLayout($pageLayout);

    if (!$pageLayout) {
        return $this;
    }

    $this->getLayout()
        ->getUpdate()
        ->addHandle($pageLayout->getLayoutHandle());

    return $this;
}
```

Second, `_renderPage()` calls `$action->getLayout()->helper('page/layout')->applyTemplate($page->getRootTemplate())`. Similar to `applyHandle()`, `applyTemplate()` applies the actual page template.

So, this explains why you can depend on the `layout_handle` as defined in the configuration XML when it comes to CMS pages. Now, let's find out why it's not dependable for categories.

Let's look at `Mage_Catalog_CategoryController::viewAction()`, which is responsible for displaying a category page:

```
public function viewAction()
{
    if ($category = $this->_initCatagory()) {
        $design = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/design');
        $settings = $design->getDesignSettings($category);

        /* ... */

        // apply custom layout update once layout is loaded
        if ($layoutUpdates = $settings->getLayoutUpdates()) {
            if (is_array($layoutUpdates)) {
                foreach($layoutUpdates as $layoutUpdate) {
                    $update->addUpdate($layoutUpdate);
                }
            }
        }

        /* ... */

        // apply custom layout (page) template once the blocks are generated
        if ($settings->getPageLayout()) {
            $this->getLayout()->helper('page/layout')->applyTemplate($settings->getPageLayout());
        }

        /* ... */
    }
    elseif (!$this->getResponse()->isRedirect()) {
        $this->_forward('noRoute');
    }
}
```

Stripping out all of the default layout logic, we're left with two pieces:

```
        // apply custom layout update once layout is loaded
        if ($layoutUpdates = $settings->getLayoutUpdates()) {
            if (is_array($layoutUpdates)) {
                foreach($layoutUpdates as $layoutUpdate) {
                    $update->addUpdate($layoutUpdate);
                }
            }
        }
```

This goes through the category's layout updates (as defined in the `Custom Layout Update` field in the admin) and applies them. This is why using `<update handle="some_handle" />` works.

And...

```
        // apply custom layout (page) template once the blocks are generated
        if ($settings->getPageLayout()) {
            $this->getLayout()->helper('page/layout')->applyTemplate($settings->getPageLayout());
        }
```

This applies the custom page template, similar to how the CMS page logic did it, using `Mage_Page_Helper_Layout::applyTemplate()`.

Now, notice something missing?

Yup, the category controller does not call `Mage_Page_Helper_Layout::applyHandle()` to apply the `layout_handle` as defined in the configuration XML. This means that you can use the `Page Layout` field to give the category a particular page template, but your `layout_update` that accompanies the template won't get applied!

Hope this clears up why your `layout_update` node isn't getting used on the category page the way you would expect it to. Magento is full of odd behavior and inconsistencies like this :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm not clear on why I need to set the update handle on Custom Layout Update if I already choose the same handle as a layout in Page Layout ? Maybe I'm not getting something about how Magento works?

Comment: I edited my answer and added significant extra detail on why your `layout_handle` isn't being applied as you would imagine it to. Hope that helps clear things up! :)

Comment: Really appreciate the time to write this as I understand now some things. Indeed is not what I expected for Magento to do. Thanks!