# Custom layout for category page - handle trouble

Tags: xml, magento, layout, module, block

I have custom module where I've created new layout

```
<config>
<global>
    <page>
        <layouts>
            <category_special translate="label">
                <label>Limited category</label>
                <template>page/limited_category.phtml</template>
                <layout_handle>special_limited</layout_handle>
            </category_special>
        </layouts>
    </page>
</global>
```

The Limited category appeared in dropdown list, and I've choosed it.
In local.xml I wrote

```
<special_limited translate="label">
    <label>Category - Limited</label>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/category_special" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/special.phtml">

        </block>
    </reference>
</special_limited>
```

The layout is works and page loads with limited_category.phtml template, but the handle isn't. It looks like catalog_category_default is on this page

Answer (score 0):

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28247085/4169139)

As described in link above - the the category controller does not call Mage_Page_Helper_Layout::applyHandle(), so custom handle for it doesn't applies. To fix it Mage_Catalog_CategoryController::viewAction() could be overwritten:

```
public function viewAction(){
   ....
   $this->addActionLayoutHandles();
   $update->addHandle($category->getLayoutUpdateHandle());
   $update->addHandle('CATEGORY_' . $category->getId());
   if ($settings->getPageLayout()) {
            $this->getLayout()->helper('page/layout')->applyHandle($settings->getPageLayout());
        }
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect example of common mus-interpretation which most of the Magento developers possess. So here I am trying to explore things more.

Actually CMS page rendering (example : home page) and category pages are uniquely renders it's pages. Means both these pages manually generating layout update handles and then load and render them. Default behaviour of Magento is quite different from these pages. This is how Magento handle a normal controller action.

```
public function someAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

`$this->loadLayout()` is what generate layout update handles and then load them. For CMS pages and category pages, you can see that such call doesn't exist. Instead they will prepare layout manually  through their controllers.I think my point is now more clear.

Now let us explore what `loadLayout()` does here.

```
public function loadLayout($handles = null, $generateBlocks = true, $generateXml = true)
{
    // if handles were specified in arguments load them first
    if (false!==$handles && ''!==$handles) {
        $this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->addHandle($handles ? $handles : 'default');
    }

    // add default layout handles for this action
    $this->addActionLayoutHandles();

    $this->loadLayoutUpdates();

    if (!$generateXml) {
        return $this;
    }
    $this->generateLayoutXml();

    if (!$generateBlocks) {
        return $this;
    }
    $this->generateLayoutBlocks();
    $this->_isLayoutLoaded = true;

    return $this;
}
```

In this method, first two lines are used to generate layout update handles. So let us concentrate on those lines. This is the first line of code.

```
if (false!==$handles && ''!==$handles) {
    $this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->addHandle($handles ? $handles : 'default');
}
```

In normal case this will add `default` layout update handle. Now let us look what `$this->addActionLayoutHandles()` does :

```
public function addActionLayoutHandles()
{
    $update = $this->getLayout()->getUpdate();

    // load store handle
    $update->addHandle('STORE_'.Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode());

    // load theme handle
    $package = Mage::getSingleton('core/design_package');
    $update->addHandle(
        'THEME_'.$package->getArea().'_'.$package->getPackageName().'_'.$package->getTheme('layout')
    );

    // load action handle
    $update->addHandle(strtolower($this->getFullActionName()));

    return $this;
}
```

It actually adds 3 type of layout update handles. They are

1. Store specific layout update handle. Ex : `STORE_default`
2. Theme & Area specific layout update handle. Ex : THEME_frontend_rwd_default
3. Action layout update handle ex : `catalog_category_view` for category pages.

So if we wrap up, in a normal case, Magento generates basically 4 layout update handles<sup>**1**</sup> and **it will not generate *layout_handle* specific layout update handle.**

### So what is the application of *layout_handles* ?

It seems that, they are normally defined for a short-cut to update page layout via a layout update XML file. ie to perform operations like this

```
<layout>
    <{some_handle}>
        <update handle="page_one_column" />
    </{some_handle}>
</layout>
```

Other than this, there is no specific use for these handles. So you should not use those handles to do some layout customization. For that you need to use other layout update handles which will be generated by default by Magento. Out of 4 layout update handles which I specified above, action layout udpate handle should be the perfect place to do modifications.

### What can we do in this case

In this case your `local.xml` should look like

```
<layout>
    <catalog_category_view>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/category_special" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/special.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_view>
</layout>
```

Thus you don't need any rewrites. You can include a block by a single layout udpate xml file.

---

<sup>1 : There are other layout update handles which will be generated by Magento by default. It uses a special event `controller_action_layout_load_before` to do this.</sup>